# Full duplex HTTP Upgrade using non-blocking Servlet 3.1 API

Tags: java, http, servlets, nonblocking, wildfly

I asked a question regarding HTTP Upgrade handling in Servlet 3.1 on [wildfly-dev](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/wildfly-dev/2014-April/002001.html) mailing list how to develop simple bi-directional full-duplex echo protocol. After few days of discussion we concluded that the following example is somewhat correct:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/upgrade")
public class AsyncEchoUpgradeServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6955518532146927509L;

  @Override
  protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req,
      final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.upgrade(Handler.class);
  }

  public static class Handler implements HttpUpgradeHandler {
    @Override
    public void init(final WebConnection wc) {
      Listener listener = new Listener(wc);
      try {
        // we have to set the write listener before the read listener
        // otherwise the output stream could be written to before it is
        // in async mode
        wc.getOutputStream().setWriteListener(listener);
        wc.getInputStream().setReadListener(listener);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
  }

  private static class Listener implements WriteListener, ReadListener {
    private final WebConnection connection;
    private final Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();

    private Listener(final WebConnection connection) {
      this.connection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    publicvoid onDataAvailable() throws IOException {
      byte[] data = new byte[100];
      while (connection.getInputStream().isReady()) {
        int read;
        if ((read = connection.getInputStream().read(data)) != -1) {
          queue.add(new String(data, 0, read));
        }
        onWritePossible();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAllDataRead() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
      while (!queue.isEmpty() && connection.getOutputStream().isReady()) {
        String data = queue.poll();
        connection.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes());
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable t) {
    }
  }
}
```

It actually works and it is the only example exchanged during our discussion that works well and we don't have to create any additional threads to handle both input and output.

What bothers me in this example is that we call explicitly onWritePossible() from within onDataAvailable().

Does anyone have any other example on HTTP Upgrade using Servlet 3.1 API? Is the example shown above correct?

Comment: I don't see why you need to do that. It should get called whenever possible anyway. And you don't need the loop inside onDataAvailable() either, for the same reason.

Comment: read [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ReadListener.html#onDataAvailable%28%29) and you'll understand that you need the loop: "Subsequently the container will invoke this method if and only if  javax.servlet.ServletInputStream#isReady() method has been called and has returned false"